# JavaScript Global Variable is not printing hello

Tags: javascript

I have got following HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Test</title>
    <script src="11jun14.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

And following JS code:

```
var globalVar = "hello";

var foo = function() {
    alert(globalVar);  
};
```

It supposed to print out hello, but it is not doing it, I have checked the javascript tool to debug it, and there is no error message, anyone got any clue why it is not printing hello?

Comment: You never call `foo()`.

Comment: How are you calling the function? or are you not calling it at all?

Comment: Oh to be honest I was doing practices at codecademy and the script was saying it would display hello, that's why I assumed, it would display, but i didn;t know I needed to call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invoke it:

```
var globalVar = "hello";

var foo = function() {
    alert(globalVar);  
};

foo();
```

Answer (score 1):

Call foo() on which event you want to show alert

Answer (score -1):

use:

```
var globalVar = "hello";

var foo = function() {
    alert(globalVar);  
};
new foo;
```